# python how to set loop execution range

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm new to Python so forgive me for such a newbie question but I have to ask.

I started from C++ and PHP, they have the operators `{` and `}` which could be used to set the loop execution range, even in VB there is such thing called "end for(while)" to define the range of the loop; But in Python, I searched for a while and I didn't see any article which can tell me that there is such thing?

I need to use the Loop to execute multiple lines of code, and I need a way to limit its execution area so the Loop won't affect the code after the Area I wish. Please tell me how can I achieve that.

Comment: Seriously? What sites have You checked? https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm, http://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

Comment: Yep, I checked it too and I didn't see it mentioned anything like "{}" or "end loop"

Comment: You can use `for i in range(n):`, which is mentioned in the website

Comment: @TonyBabarino weirdly both of those pages doesn't mention about indentation.

Comment: @user1530836 In Python it's the indentation that distincts loop's scope. Just indent the lines you want to be executed in the loop.

Comment: @Lafexlos ah, I see. Yes... this is why the OP confuses... In Python we use indentation to define block

Comment: Oh I'm sorry then, I didn't even realize that was the issue..

Comment: @user1530836 Also you can check here. http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html

Comment: Oh? so if I missed an TAB, my result in loop will be totally different? That is kinda weird for me since I started with C++ and their "{}" operators.

Comment: Don't use tabs!!  See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @user1530836: For me the indentation was no problem when I started with Python. I indented my code in other languages anyway, so it was just leaving out the brackets.

Comment: @Matthias Well, this problem is because I didn't know the Python uses indentations to form different block without brackets. So I tried use my C experience to write the code, that is why I got this question came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, consecutive lines with same amount of indentation form a 'BLOCK'

In the following example, statement 1 to 3 are in the same block.

```
for i in range(n):
    statement 1
    statement 2

    statement 3

statement 4
```

Comment: got it. Thanks for solving my confusion.